# Lua tables and screen coordinates. For every {x} at y do

Tags: ios, lua, autotouch

I'm having a little curious sense of art in programming at the moment. And I want to script my Autotouch App on my iOS to generate Pixel Art inside of another app.

I was doing this previously by typing in code to tap at the screen at one coordinate, I did this 2000+ times and it got the job done. But there should be a better, smarter way to get it done.

My test image is going to be very symetrical to make things easy.
There is a code in the Lua app that I'm using to simply tap on the screen,

```
tap(x, y)
```

But I want to set this up like:

```
tap({xTable}, y)
```

But I'm not sure if that will "tap" at each x coordinate that I've listed for the y variable.

I want to paint a pixel at one very specific coordinate, and then step 5 pixels away and paint the next one, and repeat that until the end of the line.

Is this at all possible or am I reaching beyond the language capabilities?

Edit: for some reason my phone is not blocking code when I'm asking a question, if someone sees this and wants to edit, I would be grateful.

Comment: Is `tap` a function you wrote or one from the app? Are you just looking for how to write a simple loop that does the `+5` increment and calls `tap` again?

Comment: tap is a function in the app. It will simulate a touch on the screen at the specific (x, y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this at all possible or am I reaching beyond the language capabilities?

Not even close.  I recommend you read [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/).

> ```
>  tap({xTable}, y)
> ```
>
> But I'm not sure if that will "tap" at each x coordinate that I've listed for the y variable.

Why are you not sure? Did you not write it? If not, you can trivially write it yourself given `tap`:

```
function tapxs(xs, y)
    for i,x in ipairs(xs) do
        tap(x,y)
    end
end
```

...

```
tapxs({10,20,30,40}, 10) -- tap at 10,10; 20,10; 30,10; etc.
```

> I want to paint a pixel at one very specific coordinate, and then step 5 pixels away and paint the next one, and repeat that until the end of the line.

What is "the line"? Is it purely horizontal? You could write:

```
function tapHorizontally(startX, maxX, y, increment)
    for x=startX,maxX,increment do
        tap(x,y)
    end
end
```

...

```
tapHorizontally(10,100,20,5) -- tap from 10,20 to 100,20 in 5 pixel increments
```

Of course, that's a bizarrely specific function. You'd typically write something that takes a starting x,y and ending x,y and draws between them, so you can support horizontal, vertical, diagonal lines all with the same function, but that requires [more math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm).

The bottom line is: Lua is a full blown, powerful, high level programming language. It could be used to write the very app you're tapping on, or the app you're using to generate taps, so the limits are going to be your knowledge of programming/algorithms/math/etc.

Comment: tapHorizontally() works perfectly the way I was curious about and it will be so much easier than listing in a table. I'm teaching myself little bits of Lua here and there and I'm still trying to comprehend that there are words that you can type in the code that don't mean the English words. Like increment I know is a word, but when Lua reads it, it computes something completely mathematical. Thank you!